# Override CSS that's causing logo to disappear when I scroll on Wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a wordpress theme, Harmonic, and I've gotten almost exactly the way I want. There was an error in the theme where the nav bar would flicker away then appear again when I scroll, and I was able to change it to position: fixed.

The current issue I'm having is with the logo. When I scroll, it disappears really quickly. Is there a way to make it disappear slower or, preferably, not at all?

I'm having to edit everything by using inspect element, since I can only change the CSS. The website I'm making is sttr8drop.wordpress.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try... in this class:

```
.hsContent {
 opacity: 1 !important;  /* add this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the part that says, "Providing You with your Daily Dose", you've got some javascript that's applying an opacity to the image on scroll.

This appears to be a feature of the theme as the theme's demo has the same effect.

You'll be looking for a script related to the class `skrollable` if you're wanting to change the rate at which the effect occurs.  If you want to override it entirely...

```
.skrollable {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```